# Cypress unable get the element tag name by css selector using class name

Tags: cypress

In my application want to send a name into the **search** (image below is the reference) button, I am trying using the css selector using class name but it is failing and unable to find the element, I am missing here.

[image]

I have tried using,

```
cy.get('.styles__wrapper____Y1Fs').type(name)
```

and

```
cy.get('.vbutton__baseline___3XNit fonts__letterSpacing___3l5GB styles__searchIconWrapper___19oVL styles__iconButton___LLzft').type(name)
```

Dom Image after Click,

[image]

Comment: Does the search input appear after clicking the 'Search' button ?

Comment: Yeah it appear after the click

Comment: Can you share the dom image after the click is done and the search input box is displayed.

Comment: Updated, in the same thread

Comment: I cannot see any difference in the two images. Do you see any new code being added or any existing code being modified?

Comment: because it is not changing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohl, it is not changing then there a slight modification to your locator. You forgot to miss the `space` to be replaced by `.`

So your locator should be look like,

```
cy.get('.vbutton__baseline___3XNit.fonts__letterSpacing___3l5GB.styles__searchIconWrapper___19oVL.styles__iconButton___LLzft').click();
cy.get('.vbutton__baseline___3XNit.fonts__letterSpacing___3l5GB.styles__searchIconWrapper___19oVL.styles__iconButton___LLzft').type(name);
```

first click it and then send it.